# How to create a draggable Pane in JavaFX (FXML)

Tags: java, javafx, controller, fxml

I am trying to create a draggable Pane in javaFX. The Pane is designed in FXML.(it represents a Card in a CardGame) Now I want to create the Controller. The Controller uses the onDragDetected method.

However I have no Idea how to use the Clipboardcontent class.

```
public class TileController {

  @FXML
  Pane tilePane;

  @FXML
  public void handleDragDetection(MouseEvent mouseEvent) {
    DataFormat df = new DataFormat("JavaFXNode");
    Dragboard db = tilePane.startDragAndDrop(TransferMode.ANY);
    ClipboardContent cb = new ClipboardContent();
    cb.put(df,tilePane);
    db.setContent(cb);
    mouseEvent.consume();
  }

  @FXML
  public void handleDragDone(DragEvent event) {
    System.out.println("Do something after drop here.");
  }
```

This Code wont work, because I am using the class ClipboardContent wrong. Please help me. I just want to drag the pane.

Comment: Do you want the FXML code ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to make a Draggable Node in Javafx 2.0.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17312734/how-to-make-a-draggable-node-in-javafx-2-0)

Comment: http://www.crazyandcoding.com/blog/post/javafx-make-a-node-draggable/