# JavaFX: How to drag imageview on a Pane

Tags: javafx

Can somebody give a simple example about how to set up the EventHandler for dragging imageviews on a Pane(JavaFX). For dragging I mean press the mouse on the image, drag and image should follow, then release the mouse and the imageview will stop at that location.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [correct way to move a node by dragging in javafx 2?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10682107/correct-way-to-move-a-node-by-dragging-in-javafx-2).  You might also wish to look at the [Oracle JavaFX sample Paper Doll application](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/events-tutorial/paper-doll.htm) for something more sophisticated (and complex).

Answer (score 2):

read docs first [Drag and drop in javafx](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/drag_drop/jfxpub-drag_drop.htm)
or you can do it yourself by `getMouseX` and `getMouseY` points and change the coordinates of the imageView in `AnchorPane` ....

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to try out the proposed solution with the drag and drop. I find it to be not optimal.

By doing it with drag and drop you trigger some mechanisms that are unnecessary:

- You can drag it outside of your application
- Cursor changes ...
- I also had problems that the calulation of the position delta seems to be speed dependent

Nether the less, in case someone is interested this is my code:

Main.java

```
package sample;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{
        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("sample.fxml"));

        Controller controller = new Controller();
        loader.setController(controller);

        Parent root = (Parent)loader.load();
        controller.InitUi();

        primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World");
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 300, 275));
        primaryStage.show();
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Controller.java

```
package sample;

import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.input.*;
import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane;
import javafx.scene.shape.Rectangle;

public class Controller
{
    @FXML
    private Rectangle draggable;

    private Double lastX = null;
    private Double lastY = null;

    public void InitUi()
    {
        if (this.draggable != null)
        {
            this.draggable.setOnDragOver(new EventHandler<DragEvent>()
            {
                @Override
                public void handle(DragEvent dragEvent)
                {
                    HandleMouseMovement(dragEvent.getSceneX(), dragEvent.getSceneY());
                }
            });

            this.draggable.setOnDragDetected(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
                public void handle(MouseEvent event) {
                    Dragboard db = draggable.startDragAndDrop(TransferMode.ANY);
                    ClipboardContent content = new ClipboardContent();
                    content.putString("Does not matter");
                    db.setContent(content);
                    event.consume();

                    lastX = event.getSceneX();
                    lastY = event.getSceneY();
                }
            });
        }
    }

    private synchronized void HandleMouseMovement(double sceneX, double sceneY)
    {
        double deltaX = sceneX - lastX;
        double deltaY = sceneY - lastY;

        lastX = sceneX;
        lastY = sceneY;

        double currentXAnchor =AnchorPane.getLeftAnchor(this.draggable);
        double currentYAnchor =AnchorPane.getTopAnchor(this.draggable);

        AnchorPane.setLeftAnchor( this.draggable,  currentXAnchor + deltaX*1.5);
        AnchorPane.setTopAnchor(this.draggable, currentYAnchor + deltaY*1.5);
    }
}
```

sample.fxml

```
<?import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane?>

<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.shape.Rectangle?>
<GridPane xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml" alignment="center" hgap="10" vgap="10" prefHeight="500" prefWidth="500">
    <AnchorPane>
        <Rectangle fx:id="draggable" width="40" height="50" AnchorPane.topAnchor="20" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="20"/>
    </AnchorPane>
</GridPane>
```

Comment: Ok, it seems like the speed problems had to do with multiple move events beeing  handeld at the same time. Making the `HandleMouseMovement` `synchroized` fixed that problem. (for the most part)