# JavaFX ScrollBar drag animation

Tags: animation, javafx, scrollbar

I'm currently using the JavaFX ScrollBar control, which in itself works fine - however I'm not satisfied with the "animation" of the thumb when dragging it.

More specifically:

- When I drag the thumb quickly, fast acceleration that is - the thumb animation doesn't follow immediately, but kind of "lags" behind - same behavior when I stop dragging the thumb... it takes a split second before the thumb really starts / catches up to it's intended position.

It's not an issue of heavy layout calculation or so, because I'm experiencing the same with just rendering the ScrollBar alone without any content.

Is there some option to make this "acceleration animation" / "lag" go away? - I haven't been able to find any property to set as of yet.

Thanks,

Comment: Perhaps look at the lag issue mentioned in [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10682107/correct-way-to-move-a-node-by-dragging-in-javafx-2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10682107/correct-way-to-move-a-node-by-dragging-in-javafx-2) and some of the workarounds talked about there.  Not sure if that is similar to the issue you are experiencing or not, but I guess just try the workarounds and see if it makes any difference for you.  Note that the workarounds may have negative performance connotations on the app.

Comment: Thanks! the solution found in that thread was to set the flag when running the application: "-Djavafx.animation.fullspeed=true" (note that you have to do that as part of the command line, not from within the application)

Answer (score 1):

Set the flag "-Djavafx.animation.fullspeed=true" as part of the startup command via the command line. (Note that you can't do this via "System.setProperty(...)" within the application startup...)